# Invalid Operation in Left Outer Join (in Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 queries that work fine and when I join them together with a right outer join or an inner join they work fine but a left inner join gives me the Invalid Operation error.

This is the first query:

```
SELECT tblStops.StopID, tblStops.StopNotes, tblStops.PK, tblStops.StopDescription, 
       tblStops.SequenceNum, tblStops.CustNum, tblStops.Cases, tblStops.Highlight, 
       tblStops.Warning, DateValue(Mid([PK],InStr([PK],"|")+1)) AS [Date], 
       Left([PK],InStr([PK],"|")-1) AS RouteNum
FROM tblStops
WHERE (((DateValue(Mid([PK],InStr([PK],"|")+1)))=#2/7/2019#))
ORDER BY tblStops.SequenceNum;
```

here is the second query:

```
SELECT TSDBA_DP_STOP.ROUTE_DATE, [ROUTE_ID] & '|' & [ROUTE_DATE] AS PK,
       TSDBA_DP_STOP.LOCATION_ID, [PROJECTED_DEPARTURE]-(5/24) AS PD,
       [PROJECTED_ARRIVAL]-(5/24) AS PA, [ACTUAL_ARRIVAL]-(5/24) AS AA,
       [ACTUAL_DEPARTURE]-(5/24) AS AD, [OPEN_TIME]-(5/24) AS OT, 
       [CLOSE_TIME]-(5/24) AS CT
FROM TSDBA_DP_STOP
WHERE (((TSDBA_DP_STOP.ROUTE_DATE)=#2/7/2019#));
```

and here is when I do a left outer join on them:

```
SELECT qryStopsForRoutesOnDate.StopID, qryStopsForRoutesOnDate.PK,
       qryStopsForRoutesOnDate.StopDescription, qryStopsForRoutesOnDate.SequenceNum, 
       qryStopsForRoutesOnDate.CustNum, qryStopsForRoutesOnDate.Highlight,
       qryStopsForRoutesOnDate.Warning
FROM qryStopsForRoutesOnDate 
LEFT JOIN qryStopsInfoInRoadnet ON qryStopsForRoutesOnDate.CustNum = qryStopsInfoInRoadnet.LOCATION_ID
    ORDER BY qryStopsForRoutesOnDate.SequenceNum;
```

I looked up the error and I found this page but it says nothing about query joins. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/miscellaneous/invalid-operationerror-3219?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(jeterr40.chm5003219)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue

Comment: Do `CustNum ` and `LOCATION_ID` have the same type? Does it make sense to compare a cusomer # with a location id?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes in one database we have customers are called locations (as in locations we deliver to) and in another they are called customers.  If they had different data types, woudln't they not work for the inner join and the right outer join as well?

Comment: Edit question to provide sample data as text tables.